# jobscheduler: how to reschedule a task after it's have finished?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I can't find how to reschedule a task after it's over. When I finish a job (just calling `jobFinished` in the main thread) how can I reschedule the same job ? The problem is that `jobFinished` **is not executed immediately** and if I schedule a new task **with the same id**, then the current job will be **canceled** (even if in fact it's finished) and it'll call the `onStopJob` procedure